# Using performance.now() in Dataflow Javascript UDF

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-dataflow, user-defined-functions

I am trying to get the current timestamp (in microseconds) for the Google Cloud Dataflow execution to transform BigQuery record. For this issue, I use this instruction:

```
performance.timing.navigationStart + performance.now()
```

But, it's not working. Why?
Is there any way to get microseconds in dataflow javascript UDF?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to MDN, [*performance.timing*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/timing) is deprecated and you should be using [PerformanceNavigationTiming](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigationTiming).

Answer (score 2):

Dataflow doesn't support js UDF natively. Maybe you are using some Google provided templates.

If that's the case, it uses javax.script.ScriptEngine:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/common/JavascriptTextTransformer.java#L138

So you can try it out locally to figure out what syntax it supports.

Thanks.